# How to specify package versions in a Bitbake recipe with multiple packages?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a single Bitbake recipe that creates several packages, declared by using the PACKAGES variable and specifying the contents of each package using FILE_package1, FILE_package2, etc.

I would like to specify a different version string for each package, but they all share the version string stored in ${PV}. How can I provide a different version for each package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I could be wrong, I don't think it's possible to do what you want. The `${PV}` variable is typically specified in the title of the recipe (e.g. `busybox_1.22.1.bb`) and Bitbake sets the `${PV}` variable based on that.

In order to specify different versions for each package I think you're going to have to split the recipe into multiple recipes, each one with its own version.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, you are absolutely correct. Now, it's refactoring time.